# How to set alert for any change in specific User Story or Work Item in TFS 2008

Tags: tfs, tfs-alerts

I know how to set alert for any change in Work Item(Team->Project Alert) which are assigned to my name.
But I need to track changes in particular Work Item in TFS by setting email alert against it,which is not assigned in my name.

I am using TFS 2008.
Any help will be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [2008 TFS PowerTools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=15836) then goto to Go to Team -->Alert Explorer, Click on New Alert-->Work Item Alerts-->Specific Work Item Changed-->Click OK.

Configure the properties then the filter expression and save changes.